# error while using python to plot geocode data (from CSV) using Leaflet, folium and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, leaflet, folium

I am trying to plot some geocode data to a map but something isn't working. Can someone assist me please?

[screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZCP8.jpg)

Comment: Hi!  Please post your code and not just a screenshot.  In the meantime, I'm assuming one of your addresses has a character in it that folium's popup function doesn't like.  Try `folium.Marker(lat,long], popup=folium.Popup(name, parse_html=True)).add_to(m)` in your for-loop

Answer (score 0):

It is because the header fields are not being read. Reformat the csv file and create a new file with the same data and try again

Comment: Unfortunately it was unsuccessful. This is what my csv file looks like: https://imgur.com/a/4FQ27yF

Comment: Under problems it also says >> "iterrows: Unknown word. cSpell [21,23]"